# jQuery: add row to table and the select it in DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I want to add a row to a table, and then use it as a DOM object. Suppose the following HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr class="existing-row"><td>
      <a>add new row</a>
  </td></tr>
  <tr class="existing-row"><td>
      <a>add new row</a>
  </td></tr>
</table>
```

I use the following JavaScript with jQuery to insert a row:

```
  function addNewRow(addNewRowLink)
  {
    var currentRow = addNewRowLink.closest('tr');
    currentRow.after('<tr class="added-row"><td>This is new</td></tr>');

    var newRowInDomTree = currentRow.next('tr');
    //This does not work
  }
```

The variable `newRowInDomTree` contains a `tr.existing-row` instead a `tr.added-row`. It seems that the DOM tree is not updated, but I don't undertand why.

Any ideas?

Comment: you're missing a semi-colon after the `after` statement.

Comment: @zzz,its better to have semicolon , but even if you don't give it doesn't throw any erros..

Comment: the semi-colon isn't necessary in javascript, but is allways a good practice to add one so there's no errors when minifying the code

Comment: @all: No discussion. Edited ;-)

Comment: I have found that IE throws an error if there is no semi-colon at the end of a statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code should work, except that I can't see how it is being called, so I don't know what `addNewRowLink` actually is.

An alternative would be to retain a reference to the new element when creating it. Like this:

```
function addNewRow(addNewRowLink) {
    var currentRow = addNewRowLink.closest('tr');
    var newRowInDomTree = $('<tr class="added-row"><td>This is new</td></tr>')
                               .insertAfter( currentRow );
    // newRowInDomTree will be the element you created
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the effect you're looking for can be simplified by using the right function:

instead of:

```
currentRow.after('<tr class="added-row"><td>This is new</td></tr>');
```

you should try:

```
newRowInDomTree = $('<tr class="added-row"><td>This is new</td></tr>').insertAfter(currentRow);
```

I'd venture a guess that your selection (`currentRow.next('tr')`) is happening before the element is actually added to the dom. You could try listening for an `onload` or `onreadystatechange` event to see if it's being fired later.

Answer (score 0):

How about you just do it like this?

```
$(".existing-row a").click(function() {
 newRow = $(this).parent.after('<tr class="added-row"><td>This is new</td><tr>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Give an id to the table.
ie,

```
< table id="me">

var iHtml = ' < tr class="added-row">< td>This is new asdasdasd< /td>< /tr>' ;

$('#me tr:last').after('iHtml ');
```